# yii, extra checkbox on the form

Tags: php, checkbox, yii

i dont know why theres a blank checkbox on the last, this is my view form

```
    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'peticion_id'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'peticion_id', array('readOnly'=>'true', 'value'=>$pet)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'peticion_id'); ?>
    </div>

    <div>
        <?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('createCheck', array(), $variable); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>
```

$variable is an array with all the checkbox i want to render, but even if theres no array, its making a blank checkbox, array or not, theres always an extra checkbox on the last, how to fix this?

Comment: The line works fine for me without any extra check box. please show the var_dump($variable);

Comment: the var_dumb() shows this array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Ph' (length=2)
  1 => string 'clor' (length=4)
  2 => string '' (length=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your **var_dump($variable)** gives

```
array (size=3)
 0 => string 'Ph' (length=2)
 1 => string 'clor' (length=4) 
 2 => string '' (length=0)
```

As you can see that the third value in your array is `''` having length 0. So the empty check box is created because of this empty value in the **$variable array**. 
So if you want such values to be removed from your array then use this **in your controller action** before sending it to the view

```
$variable=  array_filter(array_map('trim', $variable));
```

**now you can send the $variable safely while rendering the form.**
Hope you wont see the unrequired checkbox now.

Comment: now i realize it was you that helped me with an early problem with checkboxes, thanks again

Comment: Yes it was me... glad to meet you again :)

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `$variable = array_filter($variable);` on top of the view (or much better - in the controller/model it comes from) to get rid of any empty values that would evaluate to `false`.

Comment: This wont work if the string contains whitespaces only.

Comment: Well, in first place I do not know why would one get an array with whitespace or empty string values anyway but you are right of course :)

Comment: hahahha...actually the OP is creating an array by exploding the contents of a file which is **Not mentioned here**. So there are chances of getting some whitespaces as values in an array :)